# WAT! Failed review audit but the question is closed

Tags: support, review, review-audits

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/review/reopen/266555) is closed as too broad, rightly so despite the upvotes (if you only take into account the last question "Won't a recent Ubuntu version affect my software in any way ?" you will need more details, so it becomes unclear), has a downvote (not mine) and doesn't have active reopen votes, then why I failed the audit when I voted to leave closed?

Comment: Got me wondering - if you tried to reopen the question through the audit, would it actually register that vote?

Comment: I'm guessing it was chosen for an audit before it was closed on the 15th of may. Presumably the system builds a list of questions once and then uses them for a while.